# Magnetic and electric energy in a 2D system

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

How do I calculate the total magnetic energy in a magnetic field confined to a plane? Doing $\int \frac{B^2}{2\mu_0} da$ over the area gives me a proxy for the total energy but it doesn't have dimensions of energy. It seems that an infinitesimally small amount of energy is present in the thin plane. What am I doing wrong? The same question goes for electric fields as well.

Comment: Magnetic field cannot be confined to a plane, such field would not obey Maxwell's equations. At best, field can be concentrated to a thin slab of non-zero thickness. The standard formula applies.

Comment: How thin is the plane? The expression gives you energy per unit volume. To calculate the energy per plane with thickness dx, you need to divide the total energy by the volume of the plane, considering your plane is not infinitesimal.

Comment: @orion I was thinking of an infinitesimal plane, like the field being confined to the xy plane.

Comment: @JánLalinský Could you elaborate on why such a field wouldn't obey Maxwell's equations?

Comment: Maxwell's equations explicitly require zero divergence. This implies the field component perpendicular to the plane is zero, so the field vector, if it is non-zero, can only lie in the plane. Such field cannot be generated, according to Maxwell's equations, by any current distribution. It can only be approximated by two antiparallel current sheets that are separated by some small distance $d$. The field then exists in the space between the sheets. Going to the limit $d=0$ means the two current sheets occupy the same position and thus cancel each other, and their field vanishes.

Comment: Thinking about it some more, this is similar to electrostatic dipole layer, which is made of two sheets of opposite charge, and has electric field only inside. Here, we would have two sheets of antiparallel current, and magnetic field only inside. But making the thickness of both kinds of layer go to zero poses a problem that the system cannot be described by single density or current density function, and thus the system becomes something that is not describable faithfully by such functions and M. equations. It is something that the limiting process creates and steps out of the std theory.

Comment: To make the current di-current layer macroscopically relevant like the dipole layer is, it would have to have finite magnetic moment, which means as the current sheets approach, current densities have to increase as well, which in the limit of zero thickness means infinite current density and infinite magnetic field in the layer. Such system could have finite magnetic moment and finite non-zero energy.

Answer (score 0):

There different ways to approach electromagnetism in a 2D system.

Usually, a 2D system arises when you have invariance by translation under a certain direction, say $z$ in cartesian coordinates. Your electric and magnetic energies:
$$
U_E= \frac{1}{2}\int E^2dxdy\\
U_B= \frac{1}{2}\int B^2dxdy
$$
but they should rather be interpreted as energies per unit length in the $z$ direction.

In fact, you can prove this formula by constructing the analogy of Maxwell’s equations in 2D. The tricky part is to realize that you need to replace the curl by a scalar, so the magnetic field is a scalar (intuitively only the $z$ component survives).

However I think that this was not the application you were considering. Instead, it could happen that the support of the magnetic field is a plane, say the $x,y$ plane in cartesian coordinates. While Ján Lalinský doesn’t think it’s possible given Maxwell’s equations, I rather think that it is possible and that there is a corresponding energy.

For this I’ll need some distribution theory. In 1D, a classic result says that a distribution whose support is a single points is a finite linear combination of derivatives of the Dirac delta at that point.

**Magnetostatics**

This naturally leads to the following form of magnetic field and current density:
$$
B =\sum_{n=0}^N B^{(n)}(x,y)\delta^{(n)}(z)\\
j =\sum_{n=0}^N j^{(n)}(x,y)\delta^{(n)}(z)
$$
Maxwell’s equations give you:
$$
\begin{align}
\partial_x B_x^{(n)}+\partial_y B_y^{(n)}+ B_z^{(n-1)}&=0\\
\partial_y B_z^{(n)}-B_y^{(n-1)}&=j_x^{(n)}\\
B_x^{(n-1)}-\partial_x B_z^{(n)}&=j_y^{(n)}\\
\partial_x B_y^{(n)}-\partial_y B_x^{(n)}&= j_z^{(n)}
\end{align}
$$
and when the index $n$ takes the value $-1$ or $N+1$, then the coefficient is zero by convention. It is best to reframe it as:
$$
\begin{align}
B_x^{(N)}&=0 & B_x^{(n-1)}&=\partial_x B_z^{(n)}+j_y^{(n)}\\
B_y^{(N)}&=0 & B_y^{(n-1)}&=\partial_y B_z^{(n)}-j_x^{(n)}\\
B_z^{(N)}&=0 & B_z^{(n-1)}&=-\partial_x B_x^{(n)}-\partial_y B_y^{(n)}
\end{align}
$$
so that $B$ can be calculated by downward induction. You can check that 4th set of equations ($(\nabla\times B)_z=j_z$) are automatically satisfied when $j$ is divergence free:
$$
\partial_x j_x^{(n)}+\partial_y j_y^{(n)}+ j_z^{(n-1)} =0
$$
You are only left with 3 extra equations:
$$
\begin{align}\tag{1}
\partial_x B_x^{(0)}+\partial_y B_y^{(0)}&=0 & \partial_y B_z^{(0)} &=j_x^{(0)} & -\partial_x B_z^{(0)}&=j_y^{(0)}
\end{align}
$$
You have to view them as extra consistency equations for $j$ on top of the divergence free condition. Note that the last two guarantee the divergence free condition at $n=0$. This is to be expected, as even if $j$ is supported on a plane, $B$ is not necessarily (take for example a uniform current sheet), so you'll need these extra conditions to guarantee this.

Ján Lalinský’s claim is recovered when $N=0$, since $B=0$ so $j=0$. You can already see the effect of (1), since you would expect that as long as you have a divergence free current, i.e. $\partial_xj_x^{(0)}+\partial_yj_y^{(0)}=j_z^{(0)}=0$, there would be a solution. However (1) cannot be deduced from the divergence free condition hence the stronger constraint that $j=0$ in this case.

With $N=1$, you can already construct concrete examples. The constraints on current are only: $j_x^{(0)}=j_y^{(0)}=j_z^{(0)}=j_z^{(1)}=0$ and $j_x^{(1)},j_y^{(1)}$ satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations, in particular, uniform currents $j_x^{(1)},j_y^{(1)}$ do the the job. Physically, it means that it is the limit of two mirror symmetric, but antiparallel current sheets of vanishing separation but infinite surface current density.

Now back to energy. Intuitively, you can construct the these field configuration as the limit of fields with finite energy. The energy is obtained by looking at the corresponding limit. Usually, it will diverge, but this is hardly surprising. It is like when you have a uniform energy density, you get a diverging energy. You'll need to divide it by an appropriate power of the "volume" and you'll get a finite quantity.

For example in the previous example, say you have two antiparallel uniform current sheets at distance $d$ and current density $j = \frac{j^{(1)}}{d}$. At finite $d$, the energy is already divergent, you need to think of energy per surface. But as $d\to0$, it also diverges as $d^{-1}$. Therefore, you'll need to think of $d U_B$ as the correct rescaled energy.

In general, you'll have two scalings, one due to 2D area because $B$ is not localised and one in the $z$ direction (the previous $d$ scaling). The latter is easy to anticipate from dimensional analysis. The leading order will be given by non zero $B^{(n)}$ of smallest index $n$ which will give rise to a scaling of $d^{-2n-1}$ (note that it is consistent with the previous example). The area scaling, you'll just need to look at the polynomial growth of $B^{(n)}$. Equivalently, it is seen in the Fourier transform of $(B^{(n)})^2$, which will give a localised contribution at zero, the rescaled energy being the coefficient in front of the smallest non zero derivative of $\delta(k)$. Therefore, while the the energy will typically be infinite, there will be a generalisation of energy density which will be positive and finite.

**Electrostatics**

This time, consider this form of electric field and charge density:
$$
E =\sum_{n=0}^N E^{(n)}(x,y)\delta^{(n)}(z)\\
\rho =\sum_{n=0}^N \rho^{(n)}(x,y)\delta^{(n)}(z)
$$
Maxwell’s equations give you:
$$
\begin{align}
\partial_x E_x^{(n)}+\partial_y E_y^{(n)}+ E_z^{(n-1)}&=\rho^{(n)}\\
\partial_y E_z^{(n)}-E_y^{(n-1)}&=0\\
E_x^{(n-1)}-\partial_x E_z^{(n)}&=0\\
\partial_x E_y^{(n)}-\partial_y E_x^{(n)}&= 0
\end{align}
$$
so you have the similar induction:
$$
\begin{align}
E_x^{(N)}&=0 & E_x^{(n-1)}&=\partial_x E_z^{(n)}\\
E_y^{(N)}&=0 & E_y^{(n-1)}&=\partial_y E_z^{(n)}\\
E_z^{(N)}&=0 & E_z^{(n-1)}&=-\partial_x E_x^{(n)}-\partial_y E_y^{(n)}+\rho^{(n)}
\end{align}
$$
Similarly, the fourth set of equation is automatically satisfied from the definition by induction. This time, there is only one extra consistency condition:
$$
\rho^{(0)}=0
$$
Physically, this imposes (local) charge neutrality. Intuitively, this makes sense, as without it, you’d have an external electric field generate by this net charge simply from Gauss’ law.

The discussion about energy is the same. The energy is typically infinite, but using an appropriate scaling in surface and width, you can arrive at a finite value.

Hope this helps.